# How to change the text color for an unchecked row in xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, checkbox, datagrid

I would like to gray out the text associated to an unchecked row in my application using xaml. I tried the following, but it is getting overwritten:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
      <CheckBox Name="cbkSelect" 
                IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelectedForOrder, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
         <CheckBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
               <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
               <Style.Triggers>
                  <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                     <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
                  </Trigger>
                  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}}" Value="True">
                     <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                  </DataTrigger>
               </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
         </CheckBox.Style>
      </CheckBox>
   </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the `Foreground` color should be applied to **all cells** of a given row, you can remove the trigger. The trigger inside the `CellTemplate` will only apply to to the `CheckBox` that the style is applied to.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
      <CheckBox Name="cbkSelect" 
                IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelectedForOrder, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
         <CheckBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
               <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
               <Style.Triggers>
                  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}}" Value="True">
                     <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                  </DataTrigger>
               </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
         </CheckBox.Style>
      </CheckBox>
   </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

If you want to apply the foreground color in normal state, but not in selected state, add this `RowStyle`.

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridRow}}">
      <Style.Triggers>
         <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelectedForOrder}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
         </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
   </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

If you want to apply the style in selected state, too, add this `CellStyle`. In this case a `RelativeSource` binding is used to access the data context of the row which contains `IsSelectedForOrder`.

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}">
      <Style.Triggers>
         <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.IsSelectedForOrder, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
         </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
   </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

Comment: Thank you! For some reason, it will not allow me to change the Foreground. I can change background, weight of text, etc. but not the color of the text! Do you know how to get around this?

Comment: It seems to be getting overwritten by other properties elsewhere in the code. Is there a way to prevent that?